# Codeigniter Sessions not showing data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following error in my code:
1) the data i am storing over session is not showing up in view
2) the form validation set rules is not working.. The required is not working. Whenever i press login without entering any field it prints a.

I have auto loaded session and form validation.

Should I use php sessions or ci sessions?

Controller:

```
public function loginFormValidation()
      {
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Username','required'); //not working
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass','Password','required');
          $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class = "text-danger">', '</div>');

          if($this->form_validation->run())
          {
              $email = $this->input->post('email');
              $pass = $this->input->post('pass');

              $this->load->model('loginModel');
              $result = $this->loginModel->loginValidation($email,$pass);

              $user_id = $result->user_id;
              $user_name = $result->user_name;
              $password = $result->password;



              $arrayDb = array(
                  'user_id' => $user_id,
                  'user_name' => $user_name,
                  'password' => $password,
              );

              $this->session->set_userdata('row', $arrayDb);

              header("location:".base_url()."/Users/dashboard");

          }
          else
          {
              echo "a";
          }
      }
```

Model:

```
class loginModel extends CI_Model
{
    public function loginValidation($email,$pass)
    {
        $q = $this->db->where(['email' => $email, 'password' => $pass])
            ->get('users');

        if($q->num_rows())
        {
            return $q->row();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller where i am printing it for testing:

```
class Users extends CI_Controller
{
    public function dashboard()
    {
        echo $this->session->userdata('user_name');  // Empty no data showing
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: form validation is working... you enter nothing and a displays...

Comment: it is not working.. the field is set to required... it is not asking me anything

Comment: "whenever i press login without entering any fields it says a" this is the exact condition that you coded. form validation fails e.g. empty fields, else condition triggered, a echoed

Comment: ok i got it.. form _validation works fine... thankx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few errors and oversights.

1. You should NEVER store plaintext passwords, let alone add them to a session variable. There is no need for that. Check out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
2. You need to check whether or not the login function actually returned data, otherwise just anyone can "login" as long as they pass form validation.
3. You are setting session data with an array incorrectly according to the way you want to access the variables.

Controller:

```
public function loginFormValidation() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class = "text-danger">', '</div>');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $pass = $this->input->post('pass'); // do not store plaintext!!!

        $this->load->model('loginModel');
        $result = $this->loginModel->loginValidation($email, $pass);

        if ($result) {
            $user_id = $result->user_id;
            $user_name = $result->user_name;
            $password = $result->password;
            //https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data
            $arrayDb = array(
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'user_name' => $user_name,
                'password' => $password, // why are you storing their PLAINTEXT password in a session?!
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($arrayDb);
            header("location:" . base_url() . "/Users/dashboard");
        } else {
            echo 'login failed; bad username/password.';
        }
    } else {
        echo validation_errors();
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function loginValidation($email, $pass) {
    $q = $this->db->where(['email' => $email, 'password' => $pass])
            ->get('users');
    if ($q->num_rows() == 1) {
        return $q->row();
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Rather than reinventing the wheel check out: https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth
I personally use it an recommend it.**

Comment: I will save password in encrypted form but i was just testing as my sessions are not working... the login model function is returning data i have checked that..

Comment: then note how i am adding the session array

Comment: yeah it worked.. thankx... so what was the actual error in my code can you plz explain?
and who can i check that a session is set or not?

Comment: There is a link in the code that should clear up the session part. Basically if you are sending an array to the set session function you don't add a key at the beginning unless that's desired. Further your weren't checking if the result was correct from your database function.

Comment: I was adding the key as i want to use this function
isset($_SESSION['some_name']);

Now how can i use this?

Comment: You were assigning the session vars to an array called rows e.g. $_session['rows']['user_id'] but you wanted $_session['user_id'] ... And yes you can access it using the $_session global. Although I&amp;#39;d suggest using userdata as it doesn&amp;#39;t give you undefined index err if you dont check if isset and instead returns null if null without error.